# Pulling Images from 9GAG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way that I can use JavaScript (and jQuery) to create a webpage which shows only the images from 9GAG, loads about 5 at a time, and loads more as one scrolls down? I'm trying to make an easier way for myself to access such websites without loading all of the other garbage.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes there is. What have you tried?

Comment: Well, since people gave me a negative vote for the answer I suggest you take a look at 9GAG's [tos](http://9gag.com/tos) and figure out if you what you're going to do is permitted. You'll probably have to link to their content...

Comment: @Evert I have not tried much since I am not very fluent with JavaScript and that is why I'm asking.
elclarns I do believe its permitted, what did you get a negative vote for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [InfiniGAG](https://github.com/k3min/infinigag).

[`http://infinigag.k3min.eu/trending`](http://infinigag.k3min.eu/trending)

Returns:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "OK",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "EyVtjpq",
            "caption": "Example",
            "images": {
                "small": "http:\/\/img-9gag-fun.9cache.com\/photo\/EyVtjpq_220x145.jpg",
                "cover": "http:\/\/img-9gag-fun.9cache.com\/photo\/EyVtjpq_460c.jpg",
                "normal": "http:\/\/img-9gag-fun.9cache.com\/photo\/EyVtjpq_460s.jpg",
                "large": "http:\/\/img-9gag-fun.9cache.com\/photo\/EyVtjpq_700b.jpg"
            },
            "media": {
                "mp4": "http:\/\/img-9gag-fun.9cache.com\/photo\/EyVtjpq_460sv.mp4",
                "webm": "http:\/\/img-9gag-fun.9cache.com\/photo\/EyVtjpq_460svwm.webm"
            },
            "link": "http:\/\/9gag.com\/gag\/EyVtjpq",
            "votes": {
                "count": 0
            },
            "comments": {
                "count": 0
            }
        },
        ...
    ],
    "paging": {
        "next": "V8eFpqG"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible... I would suggest using php.  Unfortunately you won't be able to do this with only javascript because of "sandboxing" where you can only access things stored from the url the javascript originates from.

Here is how you can do it below.  With this code comes some advice: TOS are just rules, but understand the moral/ethical considerations involved when/if using this.  9gag did the work of gathering these images so that they can get money on advertising. They pay for bandwidth (and additionally for the cloudfront cdn). If you were to use this code to make a competing product or even just to circumnavigate the ads then you are stealing.  I only post this because I think that information should be free and people should be able to learn from this php code.

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.9gag.com");
preg_match('|http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d\.cloudfront\.net/photo/.+?\.jpg|',$html,$matches);
//now matches holds all the image urls which you can print to javascript/html and show
```

Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use PHP for this project. Is there no possible way to do this without it?

Comment: well you need some sort of server side language.  If it is really just for you, there may be somethings that will run in the shell or on your local machine but at any rate javascript can not pull the images for you.

Comment: Just what I needed. I think it's good practice to provide an API, people will just take what they want anyway. Making an API shows good-will towards 3rd party, such as mobile app-makers.

Answer (score 0):

Unless said websites have an api that returns the images or paths to them, you will need server-side technology for this.

Comment: How can apps such as InfiniGap for Android pull these images then? As far as I know, they are not officially certified.

Comment: Like i said, if the app provides an API, it would be easy to consume that api and provide a list of images. I don't know whether or not it has one.